# how to select multiple values in mysql database having multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[image: sample form]

this is my sample form, what i wanted to happen is that anything i wrote in any field there, when i click search it will filter all the data. For example, when i search for the posted date of "2015/11/26" and having the description of "UNIT" all the details will be shown in the table, but as you can see, even the "2015/11/27" details are also shown because it has a description of "UNIT". I know that the reason is because i was using OR as the operator, but if I use AND, it displays nothing because the other text box like PO number, etc. is empty.

can someone help me please?
thanks in advance!

this is my query sample query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_somonitoring 
where post_date ='" & posteddate.Text & "' 
or po_num ='" & ponumber.Text & "' 
or doc_num='" & docnumber.Text & "' 
or so_num='" & TextBox1.Text & "' 
or tagging='" & tagging.Text & "' 
or accnt_name='" & accntname.Text & "' 
or address='" & address.Text & "' 
or description='" & description.Text & "' 
or model_name='" & modelname.Text & "' 
or request_qty='" & requestqty.Text & "' 
or color='" & color.Text & "' 
or amount='" & amount.Text & "'
```

Comment: i think you needs to used `AND` instead of `OR` in where condition. and as per your que. if you need only `PostDate` and `Description` related condition then why you are comparing other values in where clause??

Comment: Try this : - http://hastebin.com/fuqabaguqi.sql

Comment: @Vishal yes i have already tried using AND but what happen is that it didn't show anything because of the other fields that is empty.

Comment: I suspect there is some other caveat in your query plan or _you're just confused with the actual requirement_ , If possible provide sample data along with table DDL

Comment: im sorry, what i wanted to happen is that whatever i input in any field it will filter all the data, that's why im comparing it with all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this.

```
Dim commandString as String

if postdate.Text <> Nothing or ponumber.Text <> Nothing or docnumber.Text <> Nothing or TextBox1.Text <> Nothing or tagging.Text <> Nothing or accntname.Text <> Nothing or address.Text <> Nothing or description.Text <> Nothing or modelname.Text <> Nothing or requestqty.Text <> Nothing or colAND.Text <> Nothing or amount.Text <> Nothing Then

cmdstring = cmdstring & "Where "

Dim FirstState as Integer = 0

If postdate.text <> Nothing Then

    cmdstring = cmdstring & "post_date = " & posteddate.Text
    FirstState+=1


End If

If ponumber.Text <> Nothing Then

    If FirstState > 0 Then cmdstring = cmdstring & " AND "
    cmdstring = cmdstring & "po_num = " & ponumber.Text
    FirstState+=1

End If

If docnumber.Text <> Nothing  Then

    If FirstState > 0 Then cmdstring = cmdstring & " AND "
    cmdstring = cmdstring & "doc_num = " & docnumber.Text 
     FirstState+=1

End If

If TextBox1.Text <> Nothing Then

    If FirstState > 0 Then cmdstring = cmdstring & " AND "
    cmdstring = cmdstring & " so_num = " & TextBox1.Text
     FirstState+=1

End If

If tagging.Text <> Nothing Then

    If FirstState > 0 Then cmdstring = cmdstring & " AND "
    cmdstring = cmdstring & " tagging = " & tagging.Text

End If

If accntname.Text <> Nothing  Then

    If FirstState > 0 Then cmdstring = cmdstring & " AND "
    cmdstring = cmdstring & "accnt_name = " & accntname.Text
     FirstState+=1

End If

If address.Text <> Nothing Then

    If FirstState > 0 Then cmdstring = cmdstring & " AND "
    cmdstring = cmdstring & "address = " & address.Text
     FirstState+=1

End If

If description.Text <> Nothing Then

    If FirstState > 0 Then cmdstring = cmdstring & " AND "
    cmdstring = cmdstring & "description = " & description.Text
     FirstState+=1

End If

If modelname.Text <> Nothing Then

    If FirstState > 0 Then cmdstring = cmdstring & " AND "
    cmdstring = cmdstring & " model_name = " & modelname.Text
     FirstState+=1

End If

If requestqty.Text <> Nothing Then

    If FirstState > 0 Then cmdstring = cmdstring & " AND "
    cmdstring = cmdstring & "request_qty = " & requestqty.Text
     FirstState+=1

End If

If colAND.Text <> Nothing Then

    If FirstState > 0 Then cmdstring = cmdstring & " AND "
    cmdstring = cmdstring & "colAND = " & colAND.Text
     FirstState+=1

End If

If amount.Text <> Nothing Then

    If FirstState > 0 Then cmdstring = cmdstring & " AND "
    cmdstring = cmdstring & " amount = " & amount.Text 
     FirstState+=1

End If

End If

dim cmd as MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(cmdstring,con)
```

By that you can check each field and use the proper search query

Answer (score 0):

What you need to be doing is testing like this:

```
(field1 = val1 or field1 = "")
And
(field2 = val2 or field2 = "")
And
...
```